# PHP SOAP API call with XML request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have not worked with SOAP API before.
I want to execute a SOAP API with XML data request.
I have tried but did not get success. 
https://www.getpayments.com/docs/#processrealtimetokenpayment
This is the payment gateway URL which I have want to call.

I have used below code :

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:px="https://px.ezidebit.com.au/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <px:ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment>
      <px:digitalKey>715C0799-307B-4BF4-7B1D-4153201FC0A1</px:digitalKey>
      <px:token>3723758</px:token>
      <px:paymentAmountInCents>1600</px:paymentAmountInCents>
      <px:customerName>Hiren Patel</px:customerName>
      <px:paymentReference>123456789</px:paymentReference>
    </px:ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
$soapUrl = "https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl";
$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $soapUrl );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $xml); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml) )); 
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);  
curl_close($soap_do);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
die;
```

It throws below error :

> a:ActionNotSupportedThe message with Action
>   'ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment' cannot be processed at the receiver, due
>   to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).Curl call success.

Please anyone can guide me in this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you not use SoapClient? http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: @IvoP Sorry I am not familiar with it. Can you provide me an example of it?

Comment: Vladimir already did. See how much readable your code gets. And you have less worries about maintaining xml integrity regarding special chars in your input.

Comment: the wdsl speaks of a certificate. Did you provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with SoapClient:

```
<?php

$soap = new SoapClient(
    'https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl',
    array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => 1
    )
);

$soap->ProcessRealtimeCreditCardPayment(
    array(
        'DigitalKey' => '715C0799-307B-4BF4-7B1D-4153201FC0A1',
        'Token' => '3723758',
        'PaymentAmountInCents' => '1600',
        'CustomerName' => 'Hiren Patel',
        'PaymentReference' => '123456789'
    )
);

echo $soap->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
echo $soap->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```

You can save it into the file and run with:

```
php file.php
```